# WPF .NET Core 3.1 Resource not found, but exist

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

Hello I have really annoying bug or problem. Visual Studio 19 throws me errors that my specific style/brush/image does not exist, but they are created in App.Xaml
My page.xaml has buttton:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
```

In app.xaml style defined like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" po:Freeze="true">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And Visual Studio shows:

[image]

In same line as my button, project builds and runs without any problem, but still I want fix this problem if possible. Thanks.

P.S po namespace
`xmlns:po="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"`

Comment: This kind of errors sometimes tend to disappear when you restart Visual Studio. It it works at runtime, there is not much to worry about.

Comment: Try VS Menu: Build - Batch Build - check all - [Clean], then rebuild.

Comment: Neither restart helped, neither @aepot solution helped still shows same error, after rebuild errors just pop up